Unknown outliner icon
I'm looking at the source file to use to make the blender 4.1 loading image. And there's something I've never seen before. Do you have any documentation on what it is? An object that cannot be modified, inside a collection, without access to the data. how is this possible? What is this ? I have never seen this icon in the outliner.


this is a collection instance. To create a collection instance, put some objects in a collection, then ShiftA > Collection Instance > Name of the collection. In your case the original collection is name Wire bar stool. To edit the instance, select it and CtrltA > Make Instances Real, but the link with the original objects will be lost. If you need to change the original objects, select the ones that are in the original collection.
